# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on GCP cloud functions and intend to write a functions which combines two images. But I', getting the following error when I invoke the function:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 346, in run_http_function result =
>   _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 217, in invoke_user_function return
>   call_user_function(request_or_event) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py",
>   line 210, in call_user_function return
>   self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line
>   74, in execute newIntro= generateIntroImage(nameMappings['stdName'],
>   nameMappings['stdPicture'], nameMappings['logo'],
>   nameMappings['stdYear'], nameMappings['font']) File
>   "/user_code/main.py", line 12, in generateIntroImage
>   images.append(Image.open(logo)) File
>   "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2862, in
>   open "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
>   PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/tmp/logo.jpg'

I have ran this function on my local machine and it works as expected but when I deploy it on GCP, it gives this error and crashes. Here's my function:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

def generateIntroImage(stdName, stdPicture, logo, year, typeFace):
    images = [Image.open(x) for x in [stdPicture, logo]]
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))
    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
        new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
        x_offset += im.size[0]

    font= ImageFont.truetype(typeFace, 70)
    draw= ImageDraw.Draw(new_im)
    draw.text((0, 0), stdName+"'s " +year+" Year Book", (0,0,0),font= font)
    fileName= "/tmp/test.jpg"
    new_im.save(fileName)
    return fileName
```

These images are .jpg and .png files. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Their file extension could be wrong.

Comment: I've manually checked the extensions and they seem fine

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me on Google Colab as well, apparently updating PIL version fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I faced the same problem on Google Colab. Tried your solution but I got already the latest version of PIL installed in the environment.

Answer (score 3):

PIL throws error because it cannot *identify* the image format. Most probably the reason is that the **image is corrupted** and hence cannot be read (or "identified") by pillow's `Image.open()`. For example if you try opening the image in an IPython prompt, it would fail as well.

```
In [2]: from PIL import Image
In [3]: Image.open("176678612.jpg")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3f91b2f4e49a> in <module>
----> 1 Image.open("176678612.jpg")

/opt/conda/envs/swin/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3022         warnings.warn(message)
   3023     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 3024         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3025     )
   3026 

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '176678612.jpg'
```

And the relevant piece of code handling this check is from `PIL.Image.open()`

```
"""
exception PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: If the image cannot be opened and
       identified.
"""

raise UnidentifiedImageError(
        "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
```

---

So, the fix is to delete the image, or replace it with an uncorrupted version.

Comment: Some times PIL in google colab is not able to download the image and i don't know why. there are some images which face '403 forbidden' error while we can open the link in a browser's tab.

Answer (score 0):

url = "https://github.com/repo/folder/inner_folder/branch/img.jpg?raw=true"

give "?raw=true" at the end of url

It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you need to provide a downloadable link to the image. What worked for me was click on the download image and the copy that URL.